# Facebook access token during testing

Tags: php, facebook

I am having this issue while testing.

In my app, the user clicks on a link that takes them to login and give permissions for my app.

The problem is that after I do it successfully once, I cannot do it again easily. My check for the user in the Facebook object returns that there is a user, but the access token is invalid. I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/kleelof/public_html/projects/tutor_chapter/facebook_login/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1028
```

Here is some of my code:

```
The variable $fb is set to the Facebook object before the following code is executed. .

     $user = $fb->getUser();    
     if ($user)
    {
        // get coupon code
        $coupon_code = file_get_contents(CODE_URL . "/facebookcoupon.php?email=$user_email");

        // check that the user has given the app permission to post on their wall.
        //try
        //{
            $permissions = $FB->api("/me/permissions");

            if (array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0])) 
            {
                // build attachment
                $attachment = array(
                                    'name' => $site_name,
                                    'link' => urlencode(BASE_URL . str_replace('%code%', $coupon_code, $claim_link)),
                                    'picture' => $image_link,
                                    'description' => str_replace('%code%', $coupon_code, $description),
                                    'access_token' => $FB->getAccessToken()
                                    );

                $FB->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);

                $exit_to .= "?ce=The coupon has been posted on your Facebook timeline";
            }
            else
            {
                $exit_to .= "?ce=Unable to post the coupon";
            }
        //}catch (Exception $e) 
        //{
            /*$exit_to = $FB->getLoginUrl(  
                                    array(
                                            'scope' => FB_LOGIN_SCOPE
                                            )
                                    );
        }*/
    }
    else
    {//echo("no user");
        $exit_to = $FB->getLoginUrl(    
                                    array(
                                            'scope' => FB_LOGIN_SCOPE
                                            )
                                    );
    }
```

You can see I tried to catch the error I mentioned above and just send them back to login, but then it just gets caught in a loop of going to FB and being returned.

Does anyone see something in the logic that is not correct?

Is there a better way to handle the exception? Perhaps there is something I can do to null the $user.

take care,
lee

Comment: In your code, i can't find where you set value for $user, are you sure you didn't forget to do it?

Comment: I forgot to mention it is the User object from Facebook. I have updated my post to show the assignment to $user - lee

Comment: Could you also check the value $user holds? After permissions are given.

Comment: I cannot actually get to it right now. However, this is the technique used in just about every FB tutorial out there. I think the problem is the Facebook object is caching the values. I may be looking for a way to clear the object.

Comment: There could be all sorts of problems, like if third-party cookies are not allowed in user's browser, and user is accessing your page from facebook tab, facebookSDK won't be able to save userID and your $user will always be 0

Comment: Log the access token in your `if` block: `error_log($facebook->getAccessToken());`. Then view/debug the access token in the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Re-auth the user if the token is expired.  Also, you can try using the js-sdk login and auth flow.